# Creating a loop sequence and duplicating rows within one table

Tags: ms-access

I have a table containing:

- Order Nr (Number)
- Product (Short text)
- Material (Short text)
- Date (Date)
- Amount (Number)
- From (Number)
- To (Number)

[From] and [To] repeat themselves with each [Order Nr]
How can I create in MS Access a new column containing a sequence using as boundaries values from columns [From] and [To]? (I tried concat, but it returns short text).

On top of that I would like to duplicate all of the values from other columns and paste them to the newly created rows accordingly. (That I guess would be a self-join, but I'm not sure how to proceed)

Values From and To which are my sequence boundaries have no pattern (meaning I never know how many [Products] will be in an [Order] and how will it be distributed).

[image: Table1]

into

[image: Table2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join in a sequence table to get the desired results.

Personally, I use a sequence generating query based on `MSysObjects`, but others advocate just having a table with numbers.

First, create the sequence table/query, mine is named qSequence:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Abs(ones.ID Mod 10)+(Abs(tens.ID Mod 10)*10)+1 AS Sequence
FROM MSysObjects AS ones, MSysObjects AS tens;
```

This just generates a sequence of 1 to 100, I assume that meets your needs.

Then, we can just join in the sequence table:

```
SELECT MyTable.*, qSequence.Sequence
FROM MyTable, qSequence
WHERE qSequence.Sequence BETWEEN MyTable.From AND MyTable.To
```

Comment: thank you again, would you mind if I ask how is MSysObjects created, where do I take it from?

Comment: @OlaDavids `MSysObjects` is one of the default tables that's always present and always filled with at least enough objects so you can use it to generate sequences like this. If you check _Show system tables_ in the navigation pane, you can see it. Alternatively, you can just use a table with one field named Sequence with numbers from 1 to 100 (or whatever the maximum number of the sequence you want is).

Comment: really appreciate your help